# '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

```
export interface InputProps {
    type?: string;
    name?: string;
    value?: CommonTypeTuple;
    placeholder?: string;
    label?: string;
    error?: string;
    helpText?: string;
    block?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    onChange?: ChangeHandler<string>;
    onBlur?: BlurHandler<string | number>;
}

export const Input = ({
    type = "text",
    name = "",
    placeholder,
    error,
    block = false,
    disabled = false,
    onChange = () => {},
    onBlur = () => {},
    value,
    className = "",
    ...rest
}: InputProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        onChange(e.target.value, e.target.name);
    };
    const handleBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        onBlur(e.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <StyledWrapper block={block}>
            <StyledInput
                name={name}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                error={error}
                disabled={disabled}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={value}
                className={className}
                aria-label="tm-input"
                {...rest}
            />
        </StyledWrapper>
    );
};

export const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>`
...
...
```

`onChange` and `onBlur` reports an error

```
(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) & ChangeHandler<string>'.
Type '(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeHandler<string>'.
   Types of parameters 'e' and 'value' are incompatible.
     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1977, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "type" | ... 283 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & InputProps, "type" | ... 288 more ... | "key"> & Partial<...>
```

I'm confused because I'm clearly passing `e.target.value` which is a string and the error reported assumes it is expecting two handler functions native `onChange` and custom `handleChange` with different signatures to be same.

Answer (score 3):

`React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` defines `onChange` as `(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void)`, and you are defining `onChange` as `ChangeHandler<string>`. The type you are seeing in the error message is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of these two types.

You may want to use [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) to remove the props that overlap:

```
type ReactInput = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
type InputArgs = InputProps & Omit<ReactInput, keyof InputProps>
```

```
export const Input = ({ ...{}, ...rest }: InputArgs) => { ... }
```

Comment: I feel Wex I have kept this approach before. Someone from SO had helped me for same. I was new then but now I have more clarity into Typescript. What I don't understand is why I need to do this? Even though I have different definitions of both handlers, it should be fine. Because they are just two seperate functions. Why would they intersect? See, I'm clearly calling my custom `handleChange` with string value `e.target.value` inside the native `onChange` with proper type definition of React Event. Then how do types of these two different functions intersect?

Comment: The type of your `handleChange` seems fine, I think the issue is with the `onChange` function, which has this intersection type due to how it is passed into your `Input` function: `InputProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: Ah! Got it. Let me try again with Omit

Comment: Just one question. If I change the Order of `InputProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>`, will the custom definition take precedence?

Comment: You'll still end up with an intersection type, unfortunately. It's similar to how `a + b = b + a`. If you don't want these fields to intersect you'll have use `Omit` on one of the types.

Comment: Umm...intersection  and not merging. Cool!

Comment: Okay. It doesn't work. Quoting one of error  `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.` It is similar for `onChange`. 

Here is my change

type ReactInput = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
type InputArgs = InputProps &
 Omit<ReactInput, "onChange"> &
 Omit<ReactInput, "onBlur">;

Comment: New error message, so it seems like we're on the right track! You're not quite using `Omit` correctly. Try this: `InputProps & Omit<ReactInput, 'onChange' | 'onBlur'>`

Comment: Corrected for Omit. Still the same.

Comment: By the way. The error message did not change. I just pasted the last segment from the full error message this time.

Comment: I hope you can appreciate that it's quite difficult to debug this by looking at an incomplete sample that has been taken directly from your code. Maybe try creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I tried the input component in isolation at codesandbox.io and it does not report any error. But my project does. Can be due to eslint and the way the monorepo is setup for rules. Not sure how can I produce that all mumbo jumbo created

Comment: Plus, I'm running the project through storybook and using `awesome-typescript-loader`. Error report starts at `ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/input/index.tsx:52:5 ` Could be anything. I will use `any` for now and proceed. Thanks for your help!